# Wordpress: Custom per-page sidebars?

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't spend much time with wordpress, just wondering how to ensure an administrator can add custom content to a section of the page besides the main content area?

In short, I need to allow the admin to add a different set of images - which may or may not be linked to interior pages - for each page. Just to reiterate - I need different images for each dynamically-added page.

Originally tried the multiple-post-thumbnails plugin, but it doesn't allow links. Thought widgets might do the job, but they don't seem to allow different images across different pages.

In short, I'm sure there's some sort of means by which to add an extra input area in the edit page section...just not sure on the most elegant way to do it.

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin is helpful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/per-page-sidebars/

> The Per Page Sidebars (PPS) plugin allows blog administrators to create a unique sidebar for each Page. No template editing is required.